# Error with Fiware-Cygnus installation via yum

Tags: centos6, fiware, fiware-cygnus

i am trying to install the Fireware Cygnus via yum

```
yum install cygnus-ngsi
```

But in the middle i got some erros.

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/cygnus/init.d/cygnus from install of cygnus-common-1.2.0-0.gbd4790e.x86_64 conflicts with file from package cygnus-0.13.0-0.g0c6765f.x86_64
-......
```

i checked the **/usr** directory but there is nothing with /cygnus/init.d and so on...

It is possible that there have been something before but who knows.
I also tried to clean yum repo but the error still exists. Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command in order to remove all Cygnus stuff:

```
sudo rpm -e -vv --allmatches --nodeps --noscripts --notriggers cygnus
sudo rpm -e -vv --allmatches --nodeps --noscripts --notriggers cygnus-ngsi
```

The first command will remove everything regarding Cygnus pre release 1.0.0, the second one will remove everything post release 1.0.0.

Hope this helps!

**NOTE**: from Cygnus 1.0.0 the code was split into `cygnus-common`, a library of common utils and classes for all Cygnus agents, and `cygnus-ngsi`, a NGSI specific agent (after that, other contributors have added more agents to Cygnus , such as `cygnus-twitter` by Universidad Politécnica de Valencia). That's why before release 1.0.0 Cygnus was installed as `yum install cygnus` and after 1.0.0 it is installed as `yum install cygnus-ngsi`.

Comment: Perfect..  i add the user documentation. Maybe others can use it in the future. http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/install_with_rpm/