# FiwareLab Cygnus always get error to install

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

According to this [manual](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/install_with_rpm/index.html), I've try to install Cygnus on my Centos instance of FiwareLab but always I get the following error "Permission denied".

I have used the default user "centos" but I don't get any result.
Anyone can help me? 
Thanks a lot!!

Here's a supplementary screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Try with `sudo cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/fiware.repo <<EOL` and the rest of the file. Your user has no permission to perform this operation on the specified directory.

Comment: Hello Dalton!
Thank you very much for your answer, I could install it but after finishing the installation I miss the following errors that appear in the attached image http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagedata.php?url=http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/9824162captura-de-pantalla.png.
I do not know if despite these errors the installation has concluded correctly, what opinion can you give me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems you are upgrading a previous installation of Cygnus (0.13.0), most probably from a FIWARE Lab disk image. My recommendation is you totally remove Cygnus 0.13.0 before installing version 1.7.0. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369143/error-with-fiware-cygnus-installation-via-yum) may help you.

Comment: Thank you very much frb, I followed your steps and it is already installed perfectly! http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagedata.php?url=http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/9824433captura-de-pantalla.png
Thanks to all for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you were facing was because the user has no permission to perform that operation on the specified directory.

The solution, in this case, is use `sudo`:

```
sudo cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/fiware.repo <<EOL (continue the lines)
```

I hope it had helped you.

Comment: Yes! Yes! thank you very much, this code was very helpful